# Appending Data to an existing data frame with panda

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have been trying to find a way to add information to an excel file using panda by appending it but I can't seem to get it. The information is the input from the user

Every time it runs, the data in the excel sheet seems to overwrite the one before, not appending a new row to it.

```
FirstName = input('What is your First Name? \n')
LastName = input('What is Your Last Name? \n')
ageCustomer = int(input('What is your current Age? \n'))
genderCustomer = input('What is your biological assigned gender? \n')
socialCustomer = int(input('What is your Social Security Number or ITIN? (Must Be 6 digits) \n'))
bdDayCustomer = int(input('What is the day of your birthday? (Enter Just Number) \n'))
bdMonthCustomer = int(input('What is the month of your birthday? (Enter Just Number) \n'))
bdYearCustomer = int(input('What is the year of your birthday? (Must be 4 digits) \n'))
InAmountCustomer = int(input('What is the Initial Amount Being deposited? \n'))

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'FirstN':[''],
                           'LastN':[''],
                           'Age':[0],
                           'Gender':[''],
                           'SSN':[0],
                           'bdDay':[0],
                           'bdMonth':[0],
                           'bdyear':[0],
                           'InAmount':[0],
                    })

row_to_add = pd.DataFrame({'FirstN':[FirstName],
                           'LastN':[LastName],
                           'Age':[ageCustomer],
                           'Gender':[genderCustomer],
                           'SSN':[socialCustomer],
                           'bdDay':[bdDayCustomer],
                           'bdMonth':[bdMonthCustomer],
                           'bdyear':[bdYearCustomer],
                           'InAmount':[InAmountCustomer],
                           })
df_final = df1.append(row_to_add, ignore_index=True)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('CustomerInfo.xlsx')
df_final.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print(df_final)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `mode='a'` in `pd.ExcelWriter`. Or, what exactly is the issue? "I can't seem to get it" isn't very specific.

Comment: "I can't seem to get it" isn't very clear. What is your current output and what is your expected output? Are you getting an error or is the output wrong or is there no output at all? Please [edit] your question to include more detail so that we can know how to help

Comment: Sorry, every time it runs, the data from the user just replaces and overwrites the data that was already there before, it doesn't append a new row to the excel.

Comment: See the first comment, and the [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) docs.

Comment: I did writer = pd.ExcelWriter('CustomerInfo.xlsx', mode='a') but there is an error that says ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!

Comment: `ExcelWriter` has an `engine` parameter.